# How to modify the capabilities of Shop Manager to not having access to Woocommerece setting page and no access to modify the products, only view them?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to modify the capability of 'Shop Manager' so that he/she doesn't have permission to change the Woocommerce setting, rather only has access to Woocommerce orders, reports etc.
Also Shop Manager shouldn't be able to modify the products, but only view the products.

I know the following hook can be used to add/remove the capabilities :

```
function we_update_shopmanager() {
   $shop_manager = get_role( 'shop_manager' );

   // Listing the permitted capabilities & then add the capabilities
   $caps = array(
        'manage_woocommerce',
        ...);
   foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {
        $shop_manager->add_cap( $cap );
   }

   // Listing non-permitted capabilities & then remove the capabilities
   $caps = array(
        'delete_pages'           ,
        'edit_pages'             ,
        ...);
   foreach ( $caps as $cap ) {
        $shop_manager->remove_cap( $cap );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'we_update_shopmanager', 11 );
```

Here problem is when I add the capability 'manage_woocommerce', Shop-Manager get all the permission including the Woocommerce setting section, also he has full control to modify the products.

I am not sure what capability string I should use to achieve what I am looking for.
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

You cad add below type your user capability.

```
// Add the simple_role.
function wp_shop_manager_role() {
    add_role(
        'shop_manager',
        'Shop Manager Role',
        array(
            'read'         => true,
            'edit_posts'   => true,
            'upload_files' => true,
        ),
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_shop_manager_role' );

// Add simple_role capabilities, priority must be after the initial role definition.
function wp_shop_manager_role_caps() {
    // Gets the simple_role role object.
    $role = get_role( 'simple_role' );

    // Add a new capability.
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts', true );
    // Remove a capability.
    // $role->remove_cap( 'read_private_posts' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wp_shop_manager_role_caps', 11 );
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want Shop Manager to only have access of Woocommerce orders & reports sections and can only view the Products, no access  to modify/delete them. In the above code which section is taking care of that ?

Comment: see there commented remove_cap() for remove capability and have add_cap() to add capability to use for our shop manager role. and above function add role there have permission for Read and Write you can manage or change from there